# Sql Where clause with condition to either set where clause equal to value passed or if value passed is null to set where clause to "IS NULL"

Tags: sql, case, where-clause

Sorry for the confusing title but I could not figure our a better title I will explain in greater detail here

I have two tables. The first table would return results like the one below

[image]

The second table would have more details based on not only the 'Code' but also the 'SubCode' And would return results like the ones below

[image]

I am using the tables to show a Master detail report with the first table being the Master and the second table being the detail so for example I would collect all of the details that are associated to the Master's 'Code' and 'SubCode'.

As you can see the 'SubCode' can be nullable. So when I am trying to run my detail query I am running into the problem of how to do the where clause

```
SELECT Description, Amount 
FROM TABLE2 
WHERE Code = (@AccountCodeParam) 
  AND SubCode = CASE 
                   WHEN (@SubCodeParam) IS NOT NULL 
                      THEN (@SubCodeParam) 
                      ELSE IS NULL
```

This is the query that I was trying, but it will not work due to the part where 'SubCode =' breaks the 'ELSE IS NULL'

I can't do an OR Statement because it is returning Table2 results that have 'SubCode' = NULL with table rows that do have a 'SubCode'

Did I set up my first query wrong? or is there a different way to do this any help is appreciated thank you!

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Where do you get the Description from for the records having SubCode = NULL? Is this a default value? If so you could achive your goal be using a left join plus the coalesce function,

Comment: SQL Server. I can tell from the screen shots, especially the shade of yellow they use to highlight null values.

Comment: It is Sql server sorry for the delayed response thank you all for your responses! Question for @randomDude1001 what does the coalesce function do I came across that and I really didn't know how to use it. Might be a dumb question but would a left join with the coalesce make the query faster, or would it be about the same as using Turo's answer below?

Comment: coalesce(param1, param2, ...) returns the first not null parameter. You could use this with a left join like:`COALESCE(sub.Description, 'FitPayable') as SubDescription` When you left join the root table with the _sub_ table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something like

```
SELECT Description, Amount 
  FROM TABLE2 
 Where Code = (@AccountCodeParam)
   And 
    ((SubCode = @SubCodeParam) OR (@SubCodeParam IS NULL AND SubCode IS NULL))
```

The or-Clause is true when Subcode and SubcodeParam are both not null and equal or both are null, what is, as I understand, what you want-

Answer (score 1):

If you turn off ANSI nulls, this will work in SQL Server.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF;

DECLARE @SubCodeParam varchar(20) = null;

SELECT Description, Amount 
FROM TABLE2 
WHERE Code = (@AccountCodeParam) 
  AND SubCode = @SubCodeParam;
```

This is not the "right way" to do it. I am only showing it to you in case you see it in an existing application.

For new code, use https://stackoverflow.com/a/59956686/5274

Answer (score 1):

You may prefer to do it like so, as it's a more readable code than using `OR`. Keep in mind it also prevents the use of an index on `SubCode` because the predicate is based on a function call, but it may still offer better performance than the `OR` query due to a big impact on cardinality estimates of logical or. That could be relevant if your table has a lot of data in it.

```
SELECT Description, Amount
  FROM TABLE2
 WHERE Code = @AccountCodeParam
   AND ISNULL(SubCode, -1) = ISNULL(@SubCodeParam, -1)
```

[ISNULL reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Make sure that the value picked for `NULL` substitution does not occur in your real data.

Comment: So your saying I just have to make sure that the -1 isn't used as a 'SubCode'?

Comment: The reason I am asking is because there is a lot of data and I am looking for the fastest query possible

Comment: Yes, -1 must not occur in your real data in SubCode; if it did, these rows would get returned along with NULL subcodes when you pass NULL. As for performance - measure it, and then decide which is better. If you have control over data, your best bet is to get rid of null, use a 0, -1 or whatever which will let you get rid of that OR and then slap an index on Code and SubCode, it can't get any better than that.

Comment: I strongly discourage the use of this pattern. A lot of performance problems can be attributed to it.

Comment: @JonathanAllen A lot of performance problems can be attributed to using OR irresponsibly, especially when parameter sniffing is involved. Test, measure and decide. I mentioned it prevents usage of an index, but it might actually be performing better than a corresponding OR query. It might perform worse too, it all depends on the real query being executed and a number of other factors.

Comment: Even more performance problems are caused by non-SARGable queries.